# Angular 2 service http post doesnt work

Tags: node.js, angular

I have nodejs server listening & waiting for post requests `http://localhost:3000/api/updateLocation`
Server is tested with PostMan for JSON post request and all is working, nodejs outputs 'Got data' to console. But Angular2 doesnt seems to send data to server.[Screenshot PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDagh.png)

Whats the problem?

NodeJS server.js:

```
api.post('/updateLocation', function(req, res){
  //res.send(req.body);
  console.log('Got data');
});
```

Ionic 2 home.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Service} from '../../service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers: [Service]
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, service: Service) {
    setInterval( ()=> {
      service.sendLocation({ x: '46.303344', y: '28.655268' });
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  http : any;
  url : string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/updateLocation';
  constructor(http: Http){
    this.http = http;
  }

  sendLocation(location){
    let body = JSON.stringify(location);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, { headers });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the http action, otherwise the request isn't actually fired.  It remains 'cold' until it's used.

This would work, if your api was returning a json response, for example:

```
this.http.post(this.url, body, { headers }).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data.json());           
        }
);
```

Comment: is this data variable is JSON-ed response from server? so if node answer to requiest as res.json({a:b}), then data = {a:b} ? However as you can see I subscribed without arguments, so both our answers I assume are right.

Comment: Yes, 'data' contains the response.  It's actually a Response object from the @angular/http module.  The 'data' variable can be anything you like of course.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:

1) importing Rxjs/Rx

2) Changing headers to urlencoded

3) modifying function sendLocation to this (added subscribe() method):

```
  sendLocation(location){
    let body = JSON.stringify(location);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.http.post(this.url, body, {headers: headers}).subscribe();
  }
```